# How would i replace a letter/number after a symbol in replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, character, symbols

title explains everything.
I'm wondering how i can replace ONE letter/number after this specific symbol § using the replaceAll method.

Any help is appreciated, I'm not really good with regex.

I can replace the § with nothing, but that doesn't really help, see:

```
public String removeSymbols(String text) {
        text.replaceAll("§", "");
        return text;
    }
```

```
Before replace all:

§f§c§lTa§6§lpp§e§lle §7- §8[§61.8§8]
§c§lBLACK FRIDAY SALE §7- §e§lUP TO 40% OFF

After:

1f1c1lTa161lpp1e1lle 17- 18[161.818]
1c1lBLACK FRIDAY SALE 17- 1e1lUP TO 40% OFF
```

Like i said, any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Hi there! well you could first search a pattern using the grep or something related to it in java, I think the syntax in java is with `matches`. After the match you can do the replace as you wish.

Comment: You do not need to use a regex replacement for your requirement. You can do it simply by using `String#replace`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```java
public String removeSymbols(String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("(?<=§)\\p{Alnum}", "");
}
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    §                        '§'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{Alnum}                 any ASCII letter or digit
```